# Acquire the signal and simultaneously display visual stimuli in C++

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronized

I have to acquire a signal from an external device and simultaneously display a visual stimuli an LCD screen.

The signal is sampled by a BCI device at 512 Hz and it is sent to PC with a Bluetooth connection. While I acquire this signal I have to produce on the screen some visual stimuli. The two operations have to be synchronized because the time component is crucial (I need to see the responses of brain to certain stimuli, which blinks at a certain frequency). I made both the acquisition and the stimulation, but I can not put the two things together. I have the same problem in Matlab, and I can not figure it out in C++. I do not know what solution could help me (parallelism, multithreading or something else, so any advice is welcome. I hope I was clear and comprehensive.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition and Windows XP Sp3, 32 bit.

Comment: 512 Hz.  Right, just to be sure, you want to measure response times between two events - one is the appearance of some visual stimulus on a PC screen, and the other is an analysis of a stream of brain activity at 512 Hz. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. I'm making a SSVEP-based BCI and I need to acquire the signal sampled at 512 Hz and associate to it a timestamp to know when it was pulled out. At the same time I have to present some visual stimuli, which should produce a response a SSVEP response in user's brain activity, of which I need to know the exact time when they occurred. These two applications (signal acquisition and visual stimuli) must be performed at the same time. I need to see if there is a specific response in the acquired signal when there is a certain stimulus. I hope I was clear. Thanks for your answer.